# Can SSL Chain CA's have multiple children

Tags: ssl

Can CA's have multiple children? (I know this isn't the right term) In other words, is it possible to have multiple routes for the chain available?

Let's say I have the following issuing order setup on my server:

C -> B
B-> A  (C issues B which issues A)
but I also have
D -> B (D issues B)

So if I have the certificate A setup on my server, let's assume it takes priority of B->C (or the order I put the certificates in the file).

If my browser only accepts C, I'm assuming it's gonna go A->B->C. But what if it accepted D? Would it go A->B->C and fail altogether? Or would it check A->B->C and then B->D.

At this point, I'm under the assumption that:

C -> B is one certificate (C issuing B)

D -> B is another certificate (D issuing B)

Comment: +1 The issuer name is contained in the certificate, so B cannot be issued by both C and D. Unless a certificate can have multiple issuers (maybe it can). But even if it does not, I guess an equivalent question for practical purposes would be "can I have multiple certificates for my SSL domain, and offer all of them for the browser to choose from". Seems like that should be possible, if only to support alternative crypto algorithms.

Comment: I'm not exactly sure the meaning of what I did (hence my questioning) but I downloaded an extra bundle from godaddy and copy and pasted those certificates to another "bundle." And then what happens is one certificate says "B" is issued by C. But another certificate says "B" is issued by D.

Comment: It's my experience that godaddy provides more than you need. Just use what they actually sent you.

Comment: The correct terms are "subject" and "issuer". Every X.509 certificate has a name (subject) and is signed by an issuer. Unlike PGP a X.509 certificate is signed by exactly one certificate. Root CA certificates are self-signed (issuer and subject are equal). Subsequent certificates form a tree-like structure.

Answer (score 1):

## Yes.

If C and D contain the same public key, then yes.

Certificate chain building is actually quite difficult. And, yes, there can be multiple paths.

## Example: Different self-signed root CAs.

Several roots CA are currently transitioning from SHA1 self-signed root to SHA256 self-signed roots.

And they keep the public key and the name the same.

One example is the StartCom Root certificate.

Here's a summary of CAs by that name:
* https://ssl-tools.net/certificates/1cf30e1-startcom-certification-authority (Archived [here](https://archive.is/5nXAP).)

And here are two of these CA certificates that have the same name and pubkey, but are not the same. Because the have different (self) signatures:

- SHA1 self signed: https://ssl-tools.net/certificates/3e2bf7f2031b96f38ce6c4d8a85d3e2d58476a0f.txt (Archived [here](https://archive.is/khtDL).)
- SHA256 self signed: https://ssl-tools.net/certificates/a3f1333fe242bfcfc5d14e8f394298406810d1a0.txt (Archived [here](https://archive.is/tX9Om).)